# Word wrap in longtable not working

Tags: tables, longtable, hyphenation

I have the following table, where the IP addresses are supposed to be hyphenated after every ":". They can't have dashes though. Why does "" not split the word like it shoud with the babel package? In this minimal working example i included all packages i used in the original.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{scrartcl}

% Pakete einbinden
\usepackage[english]{babel} % Englische Silbentrennung und Typografie 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % Vektorschriften benutzen
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc} % Ermöglicht UTF-Sonderzeichen als Input 
\usepackage[colorlinks=false, pdfborder=0]{hyperref} % Hyperlinks
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{tabularx} 
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{ifthen} % Ermöglicht if-Anweisungen in Latex
\usepackage{colortbl} % Farbige Tabellen
\usepackage{ragged2e} % Für Tabellen
\usepackage{pdflscape} % Ermöglicht es bestimmte Seiten im Querformat anzuzeigen
\usepackage{eurosym} % Für das Eurozeichen
\usepackage{textcomp} % Für ordentliche Darstellung von Sonderzeichen
\usepackage{lmodern} % Ein hübscherer Font
\usepackage{courier} % Ein hübscherer Font für die Result-Zeilen in der Detailbeschreibung der Schwachstellen
\usepackage[a4paper,left=10mm,top=25mm,right=10mm,bottom=26mm]{geometry}


\begin{document}
\begin{longtable}[l]{p{.12\textwidth} p{.20\textwidth} p{.23\textwidth} p{.30\textwidth}}
\multicolumn{4}{>{\columncolor{blue}}l}{Part 2. Component Compliance Summary}\\


IP Address: &  192.168.1.100 & \cellcolor{red}FAIL & \\

IP Address: &  1234:""1234:""1234:""1234:"":""3b:""1 & \cellcolor{green}PASS & \\

IP Address: &  1234:\-1234:\-1234:\-1234:\-:\-1234:\-2 & \cellcolor{green}PASS & \\

IP Address: &  1234:\-1234:\-1234:\-1234:\-:\-5647:\-3 & \cellcolor{green}PASS & \\

IP Address: &  1234:\-1234:\-1234:\-1234:\-:\-5647:\-ce:\-25 & \cellcolor{green}PASS & \\
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `""` is a shorthand available in German `babel` but not in English, so it won't work in this document. I'd probably use `hyperref`'s `\nolinkurl` for the job. (Note that `hyperref` should be loaded last.) I would also try to avoid `\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}`, usually `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` should be enough (in April 2018 `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` became the default, so if you use a current LaTeX version, you won't need the line at all.) KOMA classes like `scrartcl` and `fancyhdr` don't work together that well, you should consider `scrlayer-scrpage` instead.

Comment: Thank you for the great tips. it works now. Do you know how to prevent the font from changing in \nolinkurl ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `""` shorthand is not available in all `babel` languages. In particular it is available in all German dialects (`ngerman` etc.) but not for English dialects (`english` etc.). You can define a command that does the same as `""` with

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\nohyphenbreakpoint}{\hskip\z@skip}
\makeatother
```

Since you are loading `hyperref` (which loads `url`) I would use a command similar to `\nolinkurl`. The URL breaking algorithm works just fine for IP addresses as well.

I personally quite like the typewriter font you'd get from `\nolinkurl`, but it is more semantic to define a dedicated command for IPs and when defining it you might as well change the display style.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[a4paper,left=10mm,top=25mm,right=10mm,bottom=26mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\DeclareUrlCommand\ip{\urlstyle{same}}

\newcommand*{\cellpassfail}[1]{%
  \ifnum0#1<1
    \cellcolor{red}FAIL%
  \else
    \cellcolor{green}PASS%
  \fi
}

\begin{document}
\begin{longtable}[l]{p{.12\textwidth} p{.20\textwidth} p{.23\textwidth} p{.30\textwidth}}
\multicolumn{4}{>{\columncolor{blue}}l}{Part 2. Component Compliance Summary}\\
IP Address: &  \ip{192.168.1.100}                   & \cellpassfail{0} & \\
IP Address: &  \ip{1234:1234:1234:1234::3b:1}       & \cellpassfail{1} & \\
IP Address: &  \ip{1234:1234:1234:1234::1234:2}     & \cellpassfail{1} & \\
IP Address: &  \ip{1234:1234:1234:1234::5647:3}     & \cellpassfail{1} & \\
IP Address: &  \ip{1234:1234:1234:1234::5647:ce:25} & \cellpassfail{1} &
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

[image: The table from the MWE with nicely breaking IPs]